# Correct way to create a V8::Persistent<Object> from a V8::Handle<Object>

Tags: v8, embedded-v8

I just upgraded my V8 version to 3.20.16 (from some very old version). I can no longer use

```
Handle<Object> obj /* = ... */;
Persistent<Object> p = Persistent<Object>::New( obj );
```

to create a persistent handle to an object. The compiler suggests using `static T* v8::Persistent<T>::New(v8::Isolate*, T*) [with T = v8::Object]` instead. However, if I change my code to

```
Handle<Object> obj /* = ... */;
Persistent<Object> p = Persistent<Object>::New( Isolate::GetCurrent(), *obj );
```

the compiler complains that this function is private. How do I create a `Persistent<Object>` handle from a normal `Handle<Object>` now?

I've googled and the only thing I found was that the documentations seem to contradict each other:

- https://developers.google.com/v8/embed#handles says that persistent handles are now created using the Persistence constructor
- http://bespin.cz/~ondras/html/classv8_1_1Persistent.html indicates that `Persistence<T>::New` is still the way to go

thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [constructor](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/include/v8.h?r=16177#521) that accepts normal `Handle<T>` you don't need to dereference it.

```
Persistent<Object>::New(Isolate::GetCurrent(), obj)
```

should work.

Comment: Yep, that did it, got confused as there is also no longer a public assignment operator and I had used that in the same line where I used the constructor. For cases where the `Persistent`-Handle already exists, `Persistent<T>.Reset()` can be used.

Comment: I end up getting this page many times when I try to find out how to convert v8::Persistent to v8::Local. Here is how.

`Persistent<Function> perMyFunc;
Local<Function> localMyFunc = Local<Function>::New(isolate, perMyFunc);`

Comment: If anyone is having a similar issue with more recent versions of V8 and this doesn't work, try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22648552/1144176).